# Multivariable limit .... no L'Hopital rule?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I am looking a bit at limits for multivariable functions by myself, and I can't figure it out; my book only mentions them shortly, but now I am looking at an "assignments for those interested" and it says

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\sin(xy)}{xy} \cos(x+y)$$

But that's a $0$ over $0$ expression... ?

Do we have a L'Hopital rule for these types of functions? How would I solve it?

Comment: $\cos(x+y)\to 1$, so you can easily simplify it. You also have to be explicit about the domain, since you can't use $(x,y)=(\epsilon,0)$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you for your hint, Thomas, may I ask why we can’t use domain  (,)=(,0)?

Answer (score 7):

There is no L'Hospital's rule for multivariable limits. If the limit is to exist, you can let $(x,y)$ approach $(0,0)$ by any path. Hence, if there exists any two paths such that the limits doesn't coincide, then the limit doesn't exists overall. For example, if I make $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ along the line $(t,t)$ (with $t \to 0$), I have: $$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\sin(t^2)}{t^2} \cos(2t) = 1 \ \cos(0) = 1.$$

With this, if the limit is to exist, it will be zero. In general, if you use any line $(t, mt)$, the limit will go to $0$. If you use any polynomial path $(t, a_1t + \cdots + a_nt^n)$, the limit will also be zero. Note that no matter how many paths I've checked, *I can't conclude that the limit is zero*, because it could exist two paths that I haven't checked such that the limits give different values. Usually the strategy is to use epsilons and deltas to prove that it really is zero, or write it as a product of a limited function, by a function which goes to zero... (take the hint!)

Comment: Great answer. So we use epsilon-delta-definitions to prove the existence of a limit, and we can use the "path" way to show that a limit doesn't exist, if we can show that two paths lead to two different limits.

Comment: That's right. And if you take a single path and the limit gives a number, if the limit does exist, then it must be that number. On the other hand, if the limit along a path is, say, $+\infty$, then the limit does not exist.

Comment: Since you just entered math.stack , I'll give you a tip: you can always accept/upvote the answer that helped you the most. Most people around here appreciate the positive feedback. :)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{\sin (xy)}{xy} = 1$$

And $\cos (x + y)$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin t}t=1\qquad\lim_{t\to0}\cos t=1\qquad\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}xy=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}(x+y)=0$$